# How can I fix ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree for npm install

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, npm-install, package.json

I am relatively new to angular and self-learning currently. Previously everything was working fine up until I decided to import a lot of new things into my project. To make a small story short I found that I can delete node_modules and run npm install. after deleting it I am getting the below error when I run the npm install.

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: appla-katta@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@12.2.16
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~12.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/cdk@14.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"14.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\kavis\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kavis\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-20T10_45_13_413Z-debug-0.log
```

I'm not sure what the error means, but I think I have different versions because of which dependency error is there I guess. I tried running `npm install @angular/cdk@latest` and `ng update @angular/common` but no results. I even found some more solutions like deleting node modules, and `package_lock.json` but the npm install doesn't work.

I tried to force the npm install but then my project doesn't run because of some other reason, so I was hoping to resolve the error over here itself

Thanks

Below is my package.json content

```
{
  "name": "appla-katta",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "node build && firebase deploy",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "github:angular/fire",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^13.0.0-beta.38",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@auth0/auth0-angular": "^1.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.1.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "firebase": "^7.24.0",
    "json-server": "^0.17.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

also, I had package-lock.json which I have now removed.

Answer (score 32):

remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`.

Then try this:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: I had a newer version (14) of Angular on my PC compared to the version the app was using (13) and this worked perfectly.